# Can the execution time of PHP scripts be logged on Nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have some issues with our clients reporting some of our web pages being slow. This could be for a number of reasons but I want specifically to log the execution time of each page, without having to add something into the header and footer of each PHP script. What options are there? (if it makes a difference we are running Nginx web server and PHP-FPM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$upstream_response_time` in your `log_format` to log the amount of time that PHP-FPM spent on a request.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (additionally?), you could enable FPM access log and configure it to store request times and other data.

Then you will able to compare times reported by nginx and FPM and see if you have delays between the endpoints.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#access-format and specifically comment https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#126422

Example:

```
access.format = "%R - %u [%t] \"%m %r%Q%q\" %s %f (%{mili}d) %{kilo}M %C%%"
```

will give you log very similar to that of Apache/nginx.